# Не загружается excel файл в программу R Studio

Tags: excel, r

```
y <- read.table("PopularIndicators2.xlsx", header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                           comment.char = "", fill = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,
                           blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In read.table("PopularIndicators2.xlsx", header = TRUE, sep = ",",  :
>     line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
>   2: In read.table("PopularIndicators2.xlsx", header = TRUE, sep = ",",  :
>     incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'PopularIndicators2.xlsx'

Comment: приведена не ошибка (одна), а два предупреждения (так переводится слово «warning»). а ошибка в чём?

Comment: `read.table` предназначена для чтения файлов в текстовом формате (CSV/TSV). Для чтения файлов Excel нужно использовать специализированные пакеты.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте два пакета: writexl и readxl, они хорошо работают с .xlsx

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте прописать путь к файлу в формате C:\Folder\File, это пример, у вас путь к файлу может быть другой